# Reverse the array in Assembly Language 80X86

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, reverse

Write an assembly program that defines the following array  10  25  56  80  3 , then create procedure reverse to display the array in reverse.

I can only get the size of the array. I tried to use push/pop.

Thank you!

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h

.stack 4096

.DATA
array1 DWORD 10,25,56,80,3  DUP (?)
size1  DWORD 5
outputLbl   BYTE    "The reverse is", 0
result      BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        mov     eax,5
        lea     ebx,array1  ;get address
        call    reverse

        dtoa    result, eax
        output  outputLbl, result

_MainProc ENDP
    
reverse PROC
        
        pushad

        mov ecx, (5)/2
        mov esi,0
        mov edi,((5)-1)

L1:
        mov eax, array1[esi*4]
        mov ebx, array1[edi*4]

        mov array1[esi*4], ebx
        mov array1[edi*4], eax

loop L1

        popad

        ret
    
reverse ENDP
END
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're having trouble with: the reversing part or the displaying part.

Comment: According to your task description, seems you don't need to reverse array, just print it in reversed order.

Comment: You forgot to increment `esi` and decrement `edi` before `loop L1`. 
Also instruction `lea     ebx,array1  ;get address` before calling `reverse` is unnecessary, otherwise elements in the loop should be based on `ebx`, for instance `mov eax, [ebx+esi*4]`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.